# Find common columns between Pandas and NumPy and extract column names

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas `Dataframe` (A) and a `NumPy` array (B) below

```
A =
       M         N         C         D         E         F
0.882367  0.207342  0.959867  0.332126  0.031896  0.055734
0.640045  0.411328  0.794058  0.090374  0.629194  0.219321
0.423837  0.304872  0.370467  0.651361  0.017515  0.252440
0.865555  0.692180  0.790405  0.334760  0.863329  0.759971
0.843106  0.261376  0.385936  0.289840  0.063487  0.164913
0.881428  0.257026  0.139775  0.988289  0.953948  0.870969
0.862520  0.446840  0.754147  0.461149  0.607048  0.760438
0.839595  0.486050  0.012903  0.716871  0.155938  0.370666
0.663964  0.675242  0.066046  0.263634  0.242453  0.963562
0.761090  0.501848  0.896033  0.710318  0.581952  0.392896

B =
[[ 0.20734235  0.33212606  0.03189633]
 [ 0.41132799  0.09037417  0.6291936 ]
 [ 0.30487215  0.65136057  0.01751531]
 [ 0.69217974  0.3347596   0.86332925]
 [ 0.26137593  0.28984018  0.06348744]
 [ 0.25702646  0.98828911  0.95394809]
 [ 0.44684032  0.46114941  0.60704784]
 [ 0.4860496   0.71687057  0.15593771]
 [ 0.67524202  0.26363435  0.24245288]
 [ 0.50184753  0.71031779  0.58195151]]
```

The size of `A` is (10,6) and the size of `B` is (10,3). The columns in the NumPy array `B` are a subset of the columns in the Pandas dataframe `A`. I do not know how the subset is formed ahead of time.

How can I find a list of names of the columns in the Pandas dataframe (`A`) that are also in the NumPy array (`B`)? The **expected output should be a list `['N','D','E']`**.

**EDIT:** To create `A` and `B` above this code will work:

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,6),columns=list('MNCDEF'))
y = A.iloc[:,[1,3,4]].values
B = y.view('float64')
B[:] = y
```

Note: using this method, the numbers you get will not be identical to my data. However, for the purposes of this example it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.duplicated()` - first, combine using `pd.concat()`, then select the matching columns (can of course just select headers using `df.columns`):

```
B = pd.DataFrame(B)
df = pd.concat([B, A], axis=1).T
df[df.duplicated()].T

          N         D         E
0  0.220376  0.275217  0.029644
1  0.751950  0.170162  0.996459
2  0.597565  0.440468  0.239183
3  0.775364  0.476966  0.056998
4  0.747164  0.654597  0.056527
5  0.825209  0.699910  0.374902
6  0.800624  0.837948  0.833588
7  0.420070  0.102400  0.204857
8  0.628885  0.345432  0.172771
9  0.002239  0.868492  0.225563
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question. I actually found that with your method, the final `.T` was not even required. I just used the index of the `duplicated()` datastructure: `df[df.duplicated()].index.tolist()`.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer but the post below also works just fine for my requirements in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
for Bcol in B.T:
    cells = A.as_matrix() == Bcol.reshape(-1,1)
    cols = np.all(cells, axis=0)
    print A.columns[cols]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the post. This works just as well as the accepted answer - gave me the list I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
A.columns[np.where((A.values[...,None] == B[:,None]).all(0))[0]].tolist()
```

Basically, `A.values[...,None]` pushes all existing dimensions to the front. Another way to put it would be `A.value[:,:,None]`. So, basically we are pushing the first two dimensions to the front and creating a singleton dimension at the last axis, where broadcasting with `B[:,None]` takes place when the comparison is made. Here, `B[:,None]` would essentially mean `B[:,None,:]` to be explicit about it. Rest of the code checks for all matches along the first axis and gets the indices and indexes into the column names of `A` for the final output.

---

If you worry about performance and memory efficiency, allow me to propose an alternative solution with [`scipy's cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
out = A.columns[np.where(cdist(A.values.T,B.T)==0)[0]].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks. In this part `A.values[...,None]`, what is the `...` referring to?

Comment: @WR Added those comments into the post.

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package contains functionality to solve these type of problems; specifically, the npi.indices function:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,6),columns=list('MNCDEF'))
B = A.as_matrix()[:, [1, 3, 4]]
col_idx = npi.indices(A.as_matrix(), B, axis=1)  # gives back our [1, 3, 4] list
print(list(A.index[col_idx]))
```

Perhaps this solution might be more efficient; no idea how pandas compares for this operation.

Comment: Oh, that's nice! I have never used numpy_indexed before. On the last line, why is `A.dtypes.index` required instead of `A.index`? I'm just asking because it seems more intuitive to use `A.index` since A is a dataframe.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more it looks like the `pd.concat()` approach from above. It is almost as though that exact functionality of `pd.concat()` followed by `.duplicated()` is fully built in to numpy_indexed. If I'm right, it is really nice to have this all in one line.

Comment: The dtypes.index is simply there because I am a pandas ignoramus; first hit I got on extracting column names... I am not sure how it compares to pandas .duplicated() under the hood; in any case doing the concat first is indeed a bit inelegant I think, as far as expressing intent is concerned. And npi.indices is a much more generally applicable piece of functionality, id say. Its simply a vectorized equivalent of list.index.

Answer (score 0):

inter_list = list((a_df.columns.values).intersection(set(b_df.columns.values)))

inter_df = a_df[inter_list]